# Angular2 - Issue with [ngClass]

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a conditional class to a `div` while it seems so far that if I clicked on a particular button it adds the class to it based on the condition (which is fine), however, when I click on another button (that has the same condition) on the same page, the class gets removed from the first and assigned to the second.

**The wanted behavior:**

When clicking on a button, then clicking on another one, it shouldn't remove the class from the first one. Simply like on Facebook (where you click on `like` button of a post, then you can go to another post and click on `like` button, etc..)

**HTML**

```
<div class="agreeBtn" (click)="like(review.objectId)" [ngClass]="{'agreeBtnClicked': updateBtnWithId === review.objectId && clicked}">I agree</div>
```

**.ts**

```
like(objId){

   this.updateBtnWithId = objId;

 if(this.updateBtnWithId === objId){
        this.clicked = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: where is `updateBtnWithId` set?

Comment: @suraj inside ngClass, it's declared as a string on the code side

Comment: check my answer..

Comment: my answer still applies.. let me know if it is not clear

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not very clear for me. You've said something about `liked` property which I don't have it on my code.

Comment: I meant _if you have multiple posts_ you need to track the click status of _each post_. You are having just one common variable for tracking

Answer (score 0):

You need to revisit your logic.
This is happening because you are having a common boolean variable `clicked` and a common id `updateBtnWithId` for all your buttons. This means only one post can have the class set at a time.

You either need an array of  variables for tracking the button in the list: `clicked[]`. 
Or for your example,  have a `liked` property in each `review` object in your list of posts which set the class.

Eg:

```
<div class="agreeBtn" (click)="like(review)" [ngClass]="{'agreeBtnClicked': review.liked}">I agree</div>
```

In class

```
like(obj){
   obj.liked=true;
   //this.updateBtnWithId = objId;

/* if(this.updateBtnWithId === objId){
        this.clicked = true;
  }*/
}
```

Comment: I believe that the problem with your approach is that once you click on a button, the class will be added to all the other ones...

Comment: you are calling `like()` with one of the objects from the list and only setting its property to true..and in template for each button `div` you are checking for the particular object's property..

Comment: The thing that I forgot to mention is that `review` is a JSON value generated from the backend. So, it's not possible to use `review.liked` in this case, I'm passing it inside like(review.objectId), because I want to update the backend with the new number. In this case, I can't use your method, what to do?

Comment: In that case you will have to go with my first point..it is a hacky solution..you will have to have a list/array of boolean `liked` that you can track with your obj.id with the same length as your list of posts

Comment: @HamzaL. either way you need to refactor and revisit your existing logic

Comment: I've tried to to the array method you mentioned, but I was not lucky enough, can't you please give me a hand on it?